# TextView - Splitting Lines

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-xml

I have TextView in a FrameLayout. The Textview is aligned to the left bottom of the FrameLayout and has a specific MaxWidht.

**It currently looks like this:**

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel et
>
> alia fierent forensibus.

**What I want to achieve is this:**

> Lorem ipsum dolor
>
> sit amet, vel et alia fierent forensibus.

So basically, the text should be splitted by the width of the bottom line, not by the top line.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

**Layout.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="orem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel et alia fierent forensibus."
            android:id="@+id/txtHeader"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtDescriptionShort"
            android:maxWidth="400dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Any help is very appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `setText("Lorem ipsum dolor \n sit amet, vel et alia fierent forensibus.");`

Comment: That is a trully challenging question! I think you would have to override `TextView`s method of text renderring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution could be the following function:

```
private String format(String s, int maxLength) {
    String s2 = s.substring(s.indexOf(' ', s.length() - maxLength) + 1);
    return s.substring(0, s.length()  -  s2.length()) + "\n" + s2;
}
```

used:

```
String s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel et alia fierent forensibus."
int tvMaxLength = 45;

txtHeader.setText(format(s, tvMaxLength));
```

It works of course only for two lines of text and is error prone.

A better candidate for a function that 'fills' lines of text 'bottom-up' could look something like that.

```
private String formatMultiline(String s, int maxLength) {

    if (s == null  || s.length() == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    if (maxLength < 1) {
        return s;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    int position = sb.length() - 1;
    while (position >=  maxLength - 1) {
        position = s.indexOf(' ', position - maxLength + 1);
        sb.setCharAt(position, '\n');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Please note that I have done only very basic testing. For example the function assumes that there are no double spaces in the string.

Comment: Since the text in my TextView is dynamic and I need to dynamically set the newline, this is something I was looking for. I was just hoping that it could be easier handled using XML. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor\n\nsit amet, vel et alia fierent forensibus."
        android:id="@+id/txtHeader"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtDescriptionShort"
        android:maxWidth="400dp" />
```